# Разложить массив до первого уровня

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть массив: `[['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i']`.

Как мне его разложить до первого уровня, чтобы вышел такой массив: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'r', 't', 'g', 'j', 'u', 'i', 'y', 'i']`.

В голову приходит только циклами и проверками.

Comment: типа аналог `array_merge_recursive` нужен?

Comment: @teran, понятия не имею что это за понятие :) Мне нужно в любой способ (желательно хороший) переместить всё на первый уровень

Comment: эт пхп функция, выполняющая нужное преобразование :)

Comment: @teran, а я то думал... я же помнил, что видел где-то эту функцию уже

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Решение для общего случая, использующее функции [`isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```js
function decompose(array) {
    return Array.isArray(array) ?
        [].concat(...array.map(decompose)) :
        [array];
}

let array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i'];
let arrayDecomposed = decompose(array);
console.log(arrayDecomposed);
```

Answer (score 6):

При отсутствии квадратных скобок в элементах массива можно сделать так:

```js
var arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i'];
var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
str = str.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
arr = JSON.parse('[' + str + ']');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: У меня тоже такой вариант был :D Странноватый он

Answer (score 5):

лютое рекурсивное решение в копилку (:

```js
var data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i'];

function merge(a){

   var result = [];
   
   a.forEach(function(item){
      if(Array.isArray(item)){
         result = result.concat(merge(item)); 
      }
      
      else{
          result.push(item);
      }
   });
   
   return result;
}


var out = merge(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(out));
```

Comment: Ты тоже добавляешь `JSON.stringify` для `console.log`, потому что webstorm не умеет в вывод массивов?)

Comment: @diraria не, я просто нуб в js, как умею так и вывожу :D

Comment: ааа, ну ок)) В общем можно без `JSON.stringify`, напрямую делать `console.log(out)` и будет выводиться нормально везде, кроме webstorm :)

Answer (score 2):

Если нет внутри объектов, то...

```js
function get1DArray(arr){
    return arr.join().split(",");
}

var input = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i'];
console.log(get1DArray(input));
```

Вроде работает.

Comment: Отличный вариант. Но к сожалению объекты внутри допускаются :)

Comment: на варианте, когда элементы содержат запятую, тоже не прокатит

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без рекурсии:

1. кладем элементы в стэк
2. пока стек не пуст

   1. если элемент на вершине был простой - добавляем в результат
   2. если нет - добавляем его содержимое обратно в стэк

```js
function decompose(array) {
  var stack = array.slice();
  var result = [];
  while (stack.length) {
    var cur = stack.shift();
    if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
      stack.unshift(...cur);
    } else {
      result.push(cur);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let array = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'r', 't', ['g', ['j', 'u', 'i'], 'y'], 'i'
];
let arrayDecomposed = decompose(array);
console.log(arrayDecomposed);
```

Comment: Красиво! Быстрее работает чем рекурсия?

Comment: @diraria, без тестов сложно сказать. Может зависеть например от степени вложенности массивов, от величины массивов и т.д.