# как написать цикл который затронет все элементы многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, css, json

Есть ответ от сервера

```
{"test3":{"1":"#9a4343",
          "3":"#a98181",
          "5":"#b52b2b",
          "7":"#907c7c"},
 "test1":{"test2":{"test5":{"2":"#774c4c",
                            "4":"#cc9999"}},
          "test4":{"6":"#385f82",
                   "8":"#9a5a5a"}}}
```

нужно написать цикл который затронет все элементы многомерного массива чтобы не зависимо сколько вложений будет в массиве вывело каждый цвет в виде квадрата (массив может меняться на типовой, но при этом 
алгоритм должен работать. многомерность может быть более глубокой)
Спасибо.

Comment: Похоже на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688206/186083

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разложить массив до первого уровня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688206/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8f)

Comment: @DeanGrey, решение для массивов не подойдет для объектов

Answer (score 0):

Порядок цветных квадратов не определён, т.к. значения в объектах хранятся в не упорядоченном виде.

```js
//типа отрисовка квадратов
const draw_square = color => $( document.body ).append(`<div style="background-color: ${color}" class="square"> ${color} </div>`);
    
//рекурсивный обход объекта
const each_color = (callback, obj) => Object.values( obj ).forEach( value => typeof value === 'object' && value !== null ? each_color( callback, value ) : callback( value ) )

let data = {"test3":{"1":"#9a4343",
                     "3":"#a98181",
                     "5":"#b52b2b",
                     "7":"#907c7c"},
            "test1":{"test2":{"test5":{"2":"#774c4c",
                                       "4":"#cc9999"}},
                     "test4":{"6":"#385f82",
                              "8":"#9a5a5a"}}}
    
    
each_color( draw_square, data )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```